# Angularjs : 3 nested ng-repeat table representation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have nested ng-repeats like below :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" border=1>
  <tbody ng-repeat="list in globalList">
    <tr ng-repeat="child in list">
      <td ng-repeat="baby in child">
        {{baby.second}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I'd like to have is a table as header the `baby.title` property and as data `baby.second`

Something that looks like to this :

```
|baby.title | baby.title | ... |    ->HEADERS
--------------------------------     
|baby.second| baby.second| ... |
|baby.second| baby.second| ... |
|baby.second| baby.second| ... |    ->DATAS
```

My data structure in picture :

[image]

I don't know if that's possible with my data structure tho and I can hardly change it.

Any advices ?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: Well the best I can get for the moment is what I have posted meaning the html code :/

Comment: exposing ur data structure would be helpful

Comment: I've added the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Check this code. I added new variable in JS `$scope.longestArray`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.globalList = [
    [
      [{
        'second': "dataAA",
        'title': "titleA"
      }, {
        'second': "dataAB",
        'title': "titleA"
      }]
    ],
    [
      [{
        'second': "dataBA",
        'title': "titleB"
      }, {
        'second': "dataBB",
        'title': "titleB"
      }, {
        'second': "dataBC",
        'title': "titleB"
      }]
    ],
    [
      [{
        'second': "dataCA",
        'title': "titleC"
      }]
    ]
  ];
  $scope.longestArray = angular.copy($scope.globalList).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[0].length - a[0].length;
  })[0][0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="list in globalList">
          {{list[0][0].title}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="baby in longestArray">
        <td ng-repeat="list in globalList">
          {{list[0][longestArray.indexOf(baby)].second}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kMawfCYrs1Hvs729w81h?p=preview)

Comment: well that's almost that, however i'm getting only the first row of datas while I have severals

Comment: @DeseaseSparta Then I don't see how your data are structured. As I can see, according to your example, in `globalList` there are 9 `list`s, in every `list` there is one `child`, and in every `child` there is one `baby`. Is that correct?

Comment: @DeseaseSparta What do you mean by severals rows? You mean `first` property?

Comment: The problem is that I can have several baby, the picture is confusing sorry

Comment: So you have to give an example how do you want to show your data in case of two babies. Edit your question please.

Comment: Do I have to change my data structure or I can make it work as it is  ?